# Mapping ASP.NET MVC Model with html for radio buttons without using Htmlhelpers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a model as defined below.

```
public class Holiday
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public HolidayType Type { get; set; }
        public bool AllYears { get; set; }
    }
    public enum HolidayType
    {
        HOLIDAY1 = 1,
        HOLIDAY2,
        HOLIDAY3
    }
```

In my view i am writing html code without using htmlhelpers(specific project reason).
Now my data like name, description, date get bound to the model fields except for the radio button for `HolidayType Type`

Below is the view code. How can i get the Type value automatically populated with my input in the page.

```
@model Models.Holiday

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Holiday</title>
    <script src="~/Content/Renderer/KendoUI/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#holiday").kendoDatePicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="createholiday" action="/holiday/holiday/create" method="post">
        <label for="Name">Holiday Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" /><br />
        <label for="Description">Holiday Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" name="Description" /><br />
        <label for="Date" id="date">Date</label><br />
        <input id="holiday" name="Date"/><br />
        <label for="type">Type</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Holiday 1">Holiday 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Holiday 2">Holiday 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Holiday 3">Holiday 3<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your "specific project reason" is because you got the HTML from a web designer, then that's not a good reason.  Change the code to use helpers.  You're giving up too much functionality this way.  Otherwise, why use MVC at all?  Just use Web Pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view engine is razor, change values of RdoBtns like the following. I'm not sure, hope that works...

```
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="@Prj.Models.HolidayType.HOLIDAY1">Holiday 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="@Prj.Models.HolidayType.HOLIDAY2">Holiday 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="@Prj.Models.HolidayType.HOLIDAY3">Holiday 3<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">Female
```

in controller get gender value

```
public ActionResult YourAction(string Gender)
{
  //Your Action Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using mixture of C# and jQuery code in `doc.ready` like,

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#holiday").kendoDatePicker();

        <% if(Model.Type==HolidayType.HOLIDAY1) {%>
        $('input[value=Holiday 1]').attr('checked','checked');
        <%}else if (Model.Type==HolidayType.HOLIDAY2) {%>
        $('input[value=Holiday 2]').attr('checked','checked');
        //......

    });
</script>
```

and also, for text-boxes,

```
$('#name').val('<%:Model.Name%>');
$('#description').val('<%:Model.Description%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this stuff all in your view, then loop over a list of `Type` string-values, like this:

```
@{foreach(var holiday in new List<string>(){"Holiday 1", "Holiday 2", "Holiday 3"})
    {
        <input type="radio" name="Type" value="@holiday" @(Model.Type == holiday ? "checked='checked'" : "")>@holiday <br>      
    }
}
```

It's generally better to pass in the list in via the Model, with a new property that you could access like this:

```
@{foreach(var holiday in Model.HolidayLists) // ...etc
```

But as others have noted, in foresaking HtmlHelpers you are throwing out a really good chunk of the framework.